# network_mode: service:XXX over the bridge

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to share the same VPN container among some docker-compose projects.
Inside the same `docker-compose.yml`, `network_mode: service:vpn_container` successfully route all traffics through `vpn_container`, but I can't use that method across `docker-compose.yml`s.

More concretely: my settings below:

First, to make VPN container reachable, I made virtual bridge named "vpn_network".

`$ docker network create --driver bridge vpn_network`

Then write `docker-compose.yml`s like:

```
// docker-compose.yml with VPN container
version: '3'
services:
  vpn:
    // container config
  vpn_user1:
    // container config
    network_mode: 'service:vpn'
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: vpn_network
```

```
// docker-compose.yml without VPN container
version: '3'
services:
  vpn_user2:
    // container config
    network_mode: 'service:vpn'
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: vpn_network
```

The former one works perfectly, while the latter says:

`ERROR: Service 'vpn_user2' uses the network stack of service 'vpn' which is undefined.`

even if the `vpn` container, connected to `vpn_network`, are running.

I know that's true I didn't defined `'vpn'` service inside the latter one, but so how should I write?

--

I also want to know where the document that describes behaviors of `network_mode: 'service:XXX'` is, other than https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode (which tells not enough to me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs may have been updated since, but using the below should work across docker-compose.yml files.

```
network_mode: "container:[container name/id]"
```